# ObservableCollaction.Remove() method in the XamarinForms.iOS project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, observablecollection

The mentioned code is a part of the custom control that we have written. While removing the items from the collection view we are getting the **System.ArgumentOutofRange Exception with message Index was out of range, Must be a non-negative and less than the size of collection** on the iOS platform. The same code is working fine with the UWP and Android platform

```
                            _observableCollectionObj.Remove(data);
```

Once I am writing the above-mentioned line inside the Device.BeginInvocationOnMainThread block then everything is working fine.

I am not sure what is the reason behind this behavior and why is it working fine with Windows and Android

Comment: it sounds like you have already solved the problem, so what is your question?

Comment: I am not able to find the actual reason why this is happening

Comment: Mostly you code is asynchronous and running it via Device.BeginInvocationOnMainThread you synchronising it